# rman 'delete archivelog all’ very slow

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman

On our automated test system we use flashback all the time to reset our Oracle 11g database to a state before a test run. We noticed some of the scripts involved, started to become slower and slower. In particular the following RMAN statement takes a very long time:

**delete archivelog all**

Apparently, at that time the following SQL is executing:

```
SELECT DBINC.RESETLOGS_CHANGE#
FROM
  (SELECT RESETLOGS_CHANGE#,
    PRIOR RESETLOGS_CHANGE# NEXT_RESETLOGS_CHANGE#
  FROM V$DATABASE_INCARNATION
    START WITH RESETLOGS_CHANGE#        = :B2
  AND RESETLOGS_TIME                    = :B1
    CONNECT BY PRIOR PRIOR_INCARNATION# = INCARNATION#
  ) DBINC
WHERE DBINC.RESETLOGS_CHANGE#   <= :B3
AND DBINC.NEXT_RESETLOGS_CHANGE# > :B3
```

Table `V$DATABASE_INCARNATION` on our system already contains 72K entries. Probably because we open the database with the Resetlogs option a lot in our scripts.

What we already tried in RMAN but didn't seem to help much:

**sql "alter session set optimizer_mode=RULE";**

Any sugestions on how we can make this faster?

Oracle Database version 11.2.0.1.0 on a Windows 2008R2

Comment: Have you tried to re-create the control file? That would clean up things.